# Getting "transaction is not active" when trying to run a Spring @Transactional service method in my WAR

Tags: spring, hibernate, jboss, transactions, persistence

I'm using Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE, Hibernate 4.1.0.Final, and JBoss 7.1.1.Final.  When I try and run a service method in which I have annotated the method as @Transactional, I'm getting the following error after the transaction completes:

```
19:25:43,968 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
19:25:43,973 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/myprojectclient].[dispatcher]] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception: javax.resource.ResourceException:     IJ000459: Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffc0a80064:-6b6427d:5114500c:3bd status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:352)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:464)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:67) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:276) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.extractPhysicalConnection(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:82) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:138) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at $Proxy169.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:147) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:166) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:145) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1739) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:828) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2463) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2449) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2279) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2274) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1115) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:280) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryCompiler$3.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryCompiler.java:264) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.mainco.subco.core.repo.AbstractHibernateDAO.findByUniqueConstraint(AbstractHibernateDAO.java:100) [core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at org.mainco.subco.user.repo.RoleDaoImpl.findRoleByName(RoleDaoImpl.java:17) [user-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at org.mainco.subco.myproject.service.TrainingSessionServiceImpl.addUserLinks(TrainingSessionServiceImpl.java:222) [pd-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at org.mainco.subco.myproject.service.TrainingSessionServiceImpl.createOrUpdateTrainingSessionFromOrder(TrainingSessionServiceImpl.java:141) [pd-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318) [spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) [spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) [spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110) [spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) [spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy132.createOrUpdateTrainingSessionFromOrder(Unknown Source) at org.mainco.subco.myproject.quartz.ProcessPDWorker.createTrainingSessions(ProcessPDWorker.java:106) [classes:]
    at org.mainco.subco.myproject.quartz.ProcessPDWorker.createOrUpdateTrainingSessions(ProcessPDWorker.java:85) [classes:]
    at org.mainco.subco.myproject.quartz.ProcessPDWorker.work(ProcessPDWorker.java:67) [classes:]
    at org.mainco.subco.myproject.controller.IndexController.execute(IndexController.java:66) [classes:]
    at org.mainco.subco.myproject.controller.IndexController.refreshPD(IndexController.java:38) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:322) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:184) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:155) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
```

Here is the persistence.xml I'm using …

```
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="myprojectclientunit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <!-- <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> -->
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.ecom.domain.Product</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.ebook.domain.TableOfContentsItem</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.ebook.domain.Resource</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.ebook.domain.Ebook</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.ebook.domain.Part</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.ebook.domain.Content</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.ebook.domain.ContentTopic</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.standards.domain.AbTopic</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.standards.domain.AbStandard</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.standards.domain.AbMss</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.standards.domain.CorrelationType</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.core.domain.Grade</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.core.domain.Subject</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.ecom.domain.Contract</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.organization.domain.Country</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.organization.domain.State</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.organization.domain.Address</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.organization.domain.OrganizationType</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.organization.domain.Organization</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.user.domain.User</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.user.domain.UserContract</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.user.domain.Role</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.pd.domain.AccessCode</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.pd.domain.Link</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.pd.domain.LinkType</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.pd.domain.TrainingSession</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.pd.domain.TrainingSessionTrainer</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.pd.domain.TrainingSessionMaterial</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.pd.domain.TrainingSessionTeacher</class>
        <class>org.mainco.subco.pd.domain.SBTrainer</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name"
                value="java:jboss/subco/myprojectpersistence" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and here's how I setup my datasource/entitymanager in my Spring application context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">

    <!-- JNDI name for EntityManagerFactory is defined in src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml -->
    <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:jboss/subco/myprojectpersistence"
        id="entityManagerFactory" expected-type="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory" />

    <bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Application properties -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS" id="dataSource" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

    <tx:jta-transaction-manager />

</beans>
```

My datasources element in my $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml file looks like this …

```
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS" pool-name="MySqlDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb</connection-url>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>username</user-name>
                    <password>password</password>
                </security>
                <statement>
                    <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                    <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql"/>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
```

Any ideas how I attack this?

**Edit:**  Adding the method that I mark as @Transactional ...

```
@Service("trainingSessionService")
@Transactional
public class TrainingSessionServiceImpl implements TrainingSessionService
{
    …
    public TrainingSession createOrUpdateTrainingSessionFromOrder(final Order order)
    {
        TrainingSession trSession = m_trainingSessionDao.findByOrderNumber(order.getId());

        LOG.info("Creating/updating training session associated with order #" + order.getId() + " associated with account " + (order.getAccount() != null ? order.getAccount().getAccountName() : "unknown"));;
        if (trSession == null)
        {
            trSession = new TrainingSession();
        } // if
        // Update training session fields from the order from which it
        // originated.
        trSession.setDescription("");
        trSession.setOrderNum(order.getId());
        final Set<Organization> implementingSchools = getImplementingSchools(order);
        trSession.setImplementingSchools(implementingSchools);
        final java.util.Date startDate = order.getDay1() != null ? order.getDay1() : Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        trSession.setStartDate(startDate);
        trSession.setEndDate(order.getLastDay());
        trSession.setSubject(order.getInstituteSubject());
        trSession.setStatus(order.getStatus());
        addImplementationManager(trSession, order);
        m_trainingSessionDao.save(trSession);
        LOG.info("Finished saving training session with order id " + order.getId());
        // Adds SB coordinator and teacher links if they didn't already
        // exist before.
        addUserLinks(trSession);
        return trSession;
    }   // createOrUpdateTrainingSessionFromOrder
```

Comment: what is the transaction definition for the method `createOrUpdateTrainingSessionFromOrder`?

Comment: Is this the root exception in the trace? Sometime **Transaction is not active** might not be the underlying issue causing failure. What is the current log level? try change the log level to **trace** and see if you could find a bit more info.

Comment: @Arun, That isn't actually the method that is transactional.  I have added the method ("createOrUpdateTrainingSessionFromOrder") into my quesiton.  spiritwalker, I set "TRACE" in my Jboss log, but it didn't return anything new.

Comment: Add `<tx:annotation-driven/>` to your Spring config. Also you should probably lookup transaction manager from JBoss.

Comment: "tx:annotation-driven" is included in another applicaton context file.  What do you mean "lookup transaction manager from JBoss"?  Could you give an example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

K, found the answer for this.  The method I was using was invoking a service method within it, which was throwing an exception.  It appears the exception was canceling the transaction so that when the method returned, the error I mentioned was being reported.