# javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000459 Transaction is not active

Tags: jboss, ejb-3.0, jboss-eap-7

I am using JBOSS EAP7 and EJB3.0.
I have some functionality like whenever I got some Exception, I need to log it.
But when I get a Exception and trying to log it, I am getting an exception like Transaction is not active. I am using Container Managed Transaction and Attribute type as Required.

Please help me to resolve it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you post the full tack trace - I know it might be lengthy but I found a post on the jboss developer forum hinting that you might have a NPE (null pointer exception)

Comment: We need to see the full stack trace,this issue simply means that an error was incurred thus transaction was supposed to be marked for rollback,During the attempt to mark the transaction for rollback, the transaction is found to have already been terminated

    Per the subsequent exception, the transaction seems to have already been committed (i.e. it is reported to be in the state ActionStatus.COMMITTED)

Due to the failure while attempting to mark the transaction for rollback, the original exception is not logged.

Comment: This fixed it for me. There was an exception being thrown prior to this, which was cancelling the the transaction, causing this error. So fix the prior exception.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764839/getting-transaction-is-not-active-when-trying-to-run-a-spring-transactional-s/14780779